# ASP.NET no website after web deploy

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ftp, webserver

In Visual Studio I published my website via ftp to the server. Everything runs well, all the data is located on the webserver: the Default.aspx, all folders from the project, all the stuff.
But when I call the URL, the browser does not show me the website. It's like there is no data on the server or the browser do not understand what to do with it (www.soenke-hansen.de).
Is there anything to do for me, so that the Default.aspx is handled like an index.html or something like this?

Comment: Any variations of this post is unlikely to be good fit for SO (way too broad in current form). You'd be better off asking your web service provider how to properly upload/configure ASP.Net site on they hosting. If they don't have online help/guide consider talking to they customer support.

Comment: Check the event log on your web server and edit question to include relevant errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did not know, that there might be a special configuration for asp-website. That's a good hint, I'll check it out and call the support in last instance.
When I'm back at home, I'll also check the event log and edit my question with relevant entries.

Comment: I called the support. They use linux-servers, but ASP.NET is only available on windows-servers. It seems coherent if I think about it a second. Maybe a case of facepalming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET - websites need a windows-server, but my provider offers only linux-servers, as I found out after I contacted the support.